# Andengine - SceneTouchEvent and isActionUp don't work as expected

Tags: java, android, listener, andengine

I have a scene and within it is this code block:

What's happening is when I tap the screen, or hold and let go, the system-outs aren't corresponding to what I'm expecting.. Sometimes it acts as if it was an isActionDown(), and sometimes it spams "Up"s in my logcat when I'm holding my finger on the screen. What am I missing?

```
    setOnSceneTouchListener(new IOnSceneTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene,TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {    
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                System.out.println("Up");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
```

Comment: ur touch may not be registered actaully

Comment: change return  type from false to  ture

Comment: I think there's some property with System.out / Log.d that made it seem like it doesn't work, when I changed the system-outs to actually performing actions it worked nicely..